# How can I use Symfony validator in a test correctly?

Tags: php, symfony, validation, mocking, phpunit

I have a service class:

```
class OutletTableWriter
{
    private $validator;

    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(ValidatorInterface $validator, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->validator    = $validator;
        $this->em           = $em;

    }
// inserts outlet to db
    public function insertOutlet($outletName, $buildingName = null, $propertyNumber, $streetName, $area, $town, $contactNumber, $postcode)
    {
        $outlet = new Outlet();
        $outlet->setOutletName($outletName);
        $outlet->setBuildingName($buildingName);
        $outlet->setPropertyNumber($propertyNumber);
        $outlet->setStreetName($streetName);
        $outlet->setArea($area);
        $outlet->setTown($town);
        $outlet->setContactNumber($contactNumber);
        $outlet->setPostCode($postcode);
        $outlet->setIsActive(0);

        // $validator = $this->get('validator'); // validate constraints
        $errors = $this->validator->validate($outlet);
        if (count($errors) > 0) {
            $response = new Response('', 422, array('content-type' => 'text/html'));

            $errorsString = (string) $errors;
            $response->setContent($errorsString);
            return $response;
        }

        $this->em->persist($outlet);
        $this->em->flush(); // save

        return new Response('Outlet #'.$outlet->getId().' has been successfully saved.', 201);
    }
```

This works as expected. However I am having problems when testing the functionality of this class. I have the following test method:

```
public function testUnsuccessfulInsertOutlet()
    {
        $mockValidator  = $this->getMockBuilder(ValidatorInterface::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $mockEm         = $this->getMockBuilder(EntityManagerInterface::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();


        $outletTableWriter  = new OutletTableWriter($mockValidator, $mockEm);
        $response           = $outletTableWriter->insertOutlet(
            '', '', '', '', '', '', 'EXX 1XX'
        );

        $this->assertEquals(422, $response->getStatusCode());
    }
```

The validator should fail instead it seems like no validation is done (201 response is returned). I feel like its something to do with the way I'm mocking the validator class (does it even need to be mocked? - I tried passing in just an object of the class itself and this resulted in the following exception: `Error: Cannot instantiate interface Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface`.

I am using Symfony 3.4.6.

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the validator working in the test class based on this user's experience: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/6532

So in my test I made the following changes (when instantiating the validator):

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

$this->validator    = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->enableAnnotationMapping()->getValidator();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to tell the validator mock what to do when method 'validate' is called. e.g.

```
    $errors = ['some_error'];
    $validatorMock = $this->createMock(ValidatorInterface::class);
    $validatorMock->expects($this->once())->method('validate')->with($outlet)->willReturn($errors);
```